# Файлы загружаются не полностью

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, ftp

Через любой FTP-клиент файлы загружаются не полностью. Загрузил картинку например 500 Кб, а она загрузилась только на 320 Кб, со второго раза она загрузилась только на 100 Кб, а с третьего уже получилось на 500 Кб.

При редактировании кода - то же самое. Сохраняется только часть кода почему-то. С раза 4-6 только все нормально.

Comment: Куда, откуда загружаете? Ваш ли фтп? Каким образом загружаете? Нужно больше информации.

Comment: Вы хоть код покажите.

Comment: 1) сокет может отдавать любое колличество байт отличное от запрошеного, т.е. вызовом `read(s,buff,500000)` за один раз нельзя читать файл - нужно делать циклы (найдите примеры работы с сокетами). 2) Никто не запрещает "обрыв" соидинения. Если соидинение порвалось, то нужно или а)перечитать файл б)докачивать частями (если сервак поддерживает докачку).

Comment: Неет, я загружаю файлы не кодом, без PHP. Обычное перетаскивание файлов в FTP-клиент.

Comment: А причём тут программирование, если у вас странности в ftp клиенте?